# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException seen in SOLR on running ToParentBlockJoinQuery

Tags: solr

On running the following query with 
`q=: and fq=(
{!parent which=type:scrap v='visibility:show AND (stock:1)'}
)` we ran into the following exception :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 33554431\n\tat
org.apache.lucene.util.FixedBitSet.get(FixedBitSet.java:150)\n\tat
org.apache.lucene.search.join.ToParentBlockJoinQuery$BlockJoinScorer.nextDoc(ToParentBlockJoinQuery.java:284)\n\tat
org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.scoreAll(Weight.java:177)\n\tat
org.apache.lucene.search.Weight$DefaultBulkScorer.score(Weight.java:148)\n\tat
org.apache.lucene.search.BulkScorer.score(BulkScorer.java:35)\n\tat
org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:592)\n\tat
org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:284)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocSetNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1264)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getPositiveDocSet(SolrIndexSearcher.java:951)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getProcessedFilter(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1109)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListNC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1630)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.getDocListC(SolrIndexSearcher.java:1506)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher.search(SolrIndexSearcher.java:586)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.process(QueryComponent.java:511)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:227)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:144)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2006)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:777)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:413)\n\tat
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:204)\n\tat
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)\n\tat
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)\n\tat`
```

This used to run perfectly fine before. We increased the memory for SOLR from 3000M to 4096M and ran Optimise again and things seemed to work fine. I want to understand if this can occur again and the steps we need to take to prevent it from occurring

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you raise this to the lucene / solr users mailing list. See here for more details http://lucene.apache.org/solr/resources.html